# AJAX call only works once

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm using AJAX to check whether a user input id is in the database and if it's there a check mark is displayed if not a cross mark is displayed.

When I input an id the first time which is in the data base it works perfect, if I enter a wrong id it display the cross mark but when I change the wrong id to a new correct id the check mark is not appearing.

```
jQuery(document).on("blur", '.iboxwrap input', function() {
    var value = jQuery(this).val();
    var crntEle = jQuery(this);
    var dateValve = jQuery("#paperpublishdate").val();
    if (value) {
        //alert(value);
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            data: {
                action: 'checkwithDBlist',
                thedate: dateValve,
                theid: value
            },
            success: function(response) {
                if (response == 'Maching') {
                    jQuery(crntEle).closest('.iboxwrap').children("span").children("i").addClass('fa-check');
                } else if (response == 'Sorry') {
                    jQuery(crntEle).closest('.iboxwrap').children("span").children("i").addClass('fa-times');
                }
            },
            error: function(errorThrown) {
                alert("There was an Error in ID verification. Pleae manually check the IDs and continue");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: The information you've provided isn't enough to help you. Have you done any debugging? Was there an error in the console or the PHP code? What is the response from PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the previous class:

```
 if (response == 'Maching') {
                    jQuery(crntEle).closest('.iboxwrap').children("span").children("i").removeClass('fa-times').addClass('fa-check');
                } else if (response == 'Sorry') {
                    jQuery(crntEle).closest('.iboxwrap').children("span").children("i").removeClass('fa-check').addClass('fa-times');
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try
`jQuery(document).on("change", '.iboxwrap input', function() {....}`

Comment: While this maybe can answer the question, it's better to provide some explanations about how this code help.